# Unable to pass query parameter in RestAssured and hence returing NULL values

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

My request url is:
`http://........./api/vertex?q=id:1`

```
//Rest assured code

Response response = given().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token).                        contentType(ContentType.JSON).queryParam("q", "id:1").when().get(url);
```

It gives me blank response.

But when I am trying with postman it is giving me correct result:
Postman Response attached:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO2XU.png

I have also tried to directly send the URL i.e url = http://........./api/vertex?q=id:1

```
Response response = given().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token).                        contentType(ContentType.JSON).when().get(url);
```

Still getting NULL result.

I cannot find the reason where I am going wrong.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ":" in your query param is causing this. RestAssured will by default encode it. Try disabling Url encoding.

```
Response response = given()
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .urlEncodingEnabled(false)
    .queryParam("q", "id:1")
    .when().get(url);
```